# iOS 9 found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value. What value is not present?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I'm building a calorie counter with two fields: 
One: to enter calories per serving.
Two: to enter number of servings.

there is also a "remaining cal." label that starts at 2000. Every time a user entered a data set, the remaining calories should recalculate.

here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    //MARK:Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var enteredCalories: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var enteredServings: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var calorieCount: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Communicate user inputs into textFields through Delegate callbacks
        enteredServings.delegate = self

    //UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        //Hide the keyboard
        enteredServings.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    //MARK:Actions
    @IBAction func enterButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let startingCalories = Int(calorieCount.text!)!

        if calorieCount != nil {

        let calories = Int(enteredCalories.text!)!

        let servings  = Int(enteredServings.text!)!

        let calculation = calories * servings

        calorieCount.text = "\( startingCalories - calculation)"
        enteredServings.text = " "
        enteredCalories.text = " "

        }
    }
}
```

The first time through the process works fine. Enter any combo of cal./serving and #of servings and the app runs, and updates the remaining calorie counter label.

Whenever a second data set is entered into the text fields, I get an error telling me there is no value in one of my unwrapped optional values. Why am I getting this error if there is still a value for the cal.counter label, calories/serving field and #of servings field?

I'm brand new to programming and I know this is a question that has been asked many times. I understand what the error means, just not what it means for MY code, so I have no idea where to start to fix it.

Comment: Try to not force unwarp your value with "!" but use `try`, `if let` or `guard let` to check if the variable is non nil, then u can start working with it, the problem probably lie in one of your `let`, try `print` them and see which one cause the error

Answer (score 1):

Modify this method as below,

```
 @IBAction func enterButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let startingCalories = Int(calorieCount.text!)!

    if calorieCount != nil {

    if let calories = Int(enteredCalories.text!)!, let servings  = Int(enteredServings.text!)!{

    let calculation = calories * servings

    calorieCount.text = "\( startingCalories - calculation)"
    enteredServings.text = " "
    enteredCalories.text = " "
    }

    }
```

This would not give you a crash but not sure whether it would work as expected. Try checking the value by using breakpoints or try printing them on the console, using print().